# How to get a list of words with no vowels?

Tags: python, list

The output is fine for words with vowels however i am struggling to find a way to output words from the list without vowels. Thanks in advance for any help

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
print("Alien Name List is: ",alien_names)

vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
alien_vowels = [word for word in alien_names if any(v in word for v in vowel)]
print("Alien name list with names that include vowels: ",alien_vowels)
#works as expected

vowset = set(vowel)
for word in alien_names:
    if word in alien_names != vowel:
        print(word)
#desired output: "blyph", "wynts"
#actual output: all names
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ridiculously easy to do what you want, thankfully. Just replace `any` with `not any`:

```
alien_no_vowels = [word for word in alien_names if not any(v in word for v in vowel)]
# output: ['blyhp', 'wynts']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `set.isdisjoint`:

```
>>> *filter(set(vowel).isdisjoint, alien_names),
('blyhp', 'wynts')
```

Answer (score 1):

Random Davis already provided a good answer, here's some different code that would be closer to your attempt and is much easier to read and understand how it works for beginners:

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
alienNoVowels=[]
for name in alien_names:
    hasVowel=False
    for vowel in vowels:
        if vowel in name:
            hasVowel=True
    if not hasVowel:                       #same as  "if hasVowel==False"
        alienNoVowels+=[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your code, you just need to check which word in `alien_names` is not in `alien_vowels`:

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
print("Alien Name List is: ", alien_names)

vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
alien_vowels = [word for word in alien_names if any(v in word for v in vowel)]
print("Alien name list with names that include vowels: ", alien_vowels)
#works as expected

for word in alien_names:
    if word not in alien_vowels:
        print(word)
```

Out:

```
Alien Name List is:  ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
Alien name list with names that include vowels:  ['stena', 'venah', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'ergez']
blyhp
wynts
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it with `set.intersection`. Funny story, I have used this question as an interview question during every interview I have done in the last 7 years to see how many `for` loops does the candidate uses.

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']

[i for i in alien_names if set(i).intersection(vowel)==set()]

#Or as @superb rain remarked,
#[i for i in alien_names if set(i).isdisjoint(vowel)]
```

```
['blyhp', 'wynts']
```

Comment: And in those 7 years, nobody ever told you about `isdisjoint`? :-P

Comment: I don't see how it brings anything new other than a different way of writing the same thing :)

Comment: Well it's shorter by itself, allows shorter usage (as in my answer), and is more efficient (it stops at the first common element instead of always computing the entire intersection).

Comment: True, though the problem I ask is a bit of a variation on this and would need intersection. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit long) But very efficient ;)

EDIT - Thanks [@HilbertB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8349838/hilbertb) for this!
We should replace `if x in names_with_vowels: pass` with `if not x in names_with_vowels:`, here is the old code  , and the new one is below)

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
print("Alien Name List is: ", alien_names)

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

names_with_vowels = []
for x in alien_names:
    for y in vowels:
        if x in names_with_vowels:
            pass
        else:
            if y in x:
                names_with_vowels.append(x)
print(names_with_vowels)

names_without_vowels = []
for x in alien_names:
    if x in names_with_vowels:
        pass
    else:
        names_without_vowels.append(x)
print(names_without_vowels)
```

EDIT - Thanks [@HilbertB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8349838/hilbertb) for this! New code -

```
alien_names = ['stena', 'venah', 'blyhp', 'spiuy', 'elbas', 'wynts', 'ergez']
print("Alien Name List is: ",alien_names)

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

names_with_vowels = []
for x in alien_names:
    for y in vowels:
        if not x in names_with_vowels:
            if y in x:
                names_with_vowels.append(x)
print(names_with_vowels)

names_without_vowels = []
for x in alien_names:
    if not x in names_with_vowels:
        names_without_vowels.append(x)
print(names_without_vowels)
```

Comment: Generally speaking I would never do a `if` condition with a pass in it and instead use `if not condition:`. In this case just writing `if not x in names_with_vowels:` seems like a better approach.

Comment: @HilbertB, `if x not in names_with_vowels:` would be more readable, IMO.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I could've sworn PEP 8 also prefers that, but apparently I confused it with `is not` (which it prefers over `not ... is`).

Comment: @JustinEzequiel As for readability I'd agree, I think I just default to putting the negation of a boolean at the beggining of any given statement out of habit.